# Difference between static friction and kinetic friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I don't understand the difference between static friction and kinetic friction.
I understand that the force of frictional force acting on a stationary object is the static frictional force and we use the coefficient of static friction to determine the minimum force needed to start the object moving, but once the object is moving, the frictional force can be static and kinetic and I don't understand how to differentiate between the two cases.
For example:
When car accelerates gently to a higher speed, the frictional force acting on it is static friction, why ? Why not kinetic ?
If a car "floors it" and peels out of a stop light, the friction is kinetic, why ?
A car takes a turn gently. Static. Again, how and why ?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter whether the *object itself* is moving; what matters is whether the two surfaces involved are *sliding past each other*. If they are sliding past each other, the friction is kinetic; in contrast, if they are not, then the friction is static.

When a wheel rolls without slipping/skidding, the part of the wheel that touches the ground does *not* slide along the ground, and so the friction involved is static. In contrast, when a wheel slips/skids, the part of the wheel that touches the ground slides along the ground, and so kinetic friction is involved.

Applying the above, when a car accelerates gently, the wheels do not skid, so static friction is involved. When a car "floors it" and the wheels skid, kinetic friction is involved. When a car turns gently, without skidding/drifting, static friction is involved. When a car turns quickly enough to skid/drift, kinetic friction is involved.

Comment: Okay thank you so much but if a car is moving at a constant speed, then is the friction kinetic or static ? The car is not sliding it's just moving.

Comment: @Jaca There is no friction involved at all there :) Similar to a book sitting on a table.

Comment: @AaronStevens With air resistance etc a car moving at constant speed will have a frictional force acting on it due to the ground. With no slipping/skidding the friction is static otherwise it is kinetic.

Comment: @Farcher If the car is moving at a constant speed, it's already countering the torque on the wheels from air resistance with an equal and opposite torque from the motor. This means there's no net force at the point of contact.

Comment: @probably_someone Assume the whole car is the system moving at constant velocity. Where is the ground pushing the car in the forward direction? There is no jet/rocket/propellor attached to the car. Think of the car on ice with air resistance acting and no frictional forces between the tyres and the ground.

Comment: @probably_someone Static friction is involved. If the wheel is not slipping, the wind resistance is countered by the engine applying torque against the tires static friction. Oil or ice that would lower the co-efficient of the static friction could cause slipping

Comment: @AdrianHoward Where did I say static friction wasn't involved? All I said was that there was no net force at the point of contact.

Comment: @probably_someone While there is no net force on the car, isn't there force applied to the air in front of the car countered by equal and opposite force against the static friction of the tire? Apologies if I am wrong.

Comment: @AdrianHoward Yes, and that's why I said the ***net*** force is zero. If you add the force of air resistance on the car and the static friction force exerted by the ground on the points of contact, you get zero.

Comment: @Farcher If the car is on ice (by "ice" I assume you mean something basically frictionless), and there is air resistance, then the car ***cannot*** travel at a constant nonzero speed, because there is ***no way*** for the motor to exert tangential force on the ground, the reaction from which would counter air resistance. Since we have assumed that the car is traveling at constant speed (i.e. since the OP specifically asked about a car traveling at constant speed), we have assumed that we are ***not*** considering the situation you just described.

Comment: @probably_someone But this means that there _is_ a friction force acting on the vehicle, which was the clarifying question OP asked (and Aaron said "there is no friction involved").  Your statements seemed to be supporting that there was no friction involved, which doesn't seem correct when the car is moving with a constant velocity and some form of resistance.

Comment: @JMac Well then, I apologize for creating the impression that I was supporting that statement. Nowhere did I say it, and nowhere did I intend it.

Comment: @JMac As an aside, there's a chance that this confusion was caused by a difference in definitions of the word "involved", so it might be worthwhile asking Aaron what his intended definition for that word is.

Answer (score 0):

Static friction tries to prevent relative motion between two surfaces when the surfaces that are not moving relative to one another, whereas kinetic friction tries to reduce the relative motion between two surfaces.

If at the point of contact there is no relative movement between the tire and the road then the frictional forces involved are static whereas if there is relative movement between the tyre and the road, due to slipping/sliding/skidding, the frictional forces involved are kinetic/dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

Probably someone has already explained but I would like to add few points:-

> Static friction opposes impending motion while
>   Kinetic friction opposes relative motion.